# MKOverlay dismissing under buildings

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I'm currently working with MKOverlays in the Apple MapKit. 
I try to draw rooms inside of buildings and when I put the map into 3D mode the rooms dismiss and are displayed below the buildings in the map.

Here's how I add them to the map:

```
let overlays = ETS.Map.shapes(shapes, forFloor: floor)
self.mapView.addOverlays(overlays, level: .aboveLabels)
```

I also tried level: .aboveRoads.

Here are two pictures how it looks like:

[image: Shows the room on top of the building]
[image: Shows the room hidden behind the building when map turns to 3D mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about sea levels when working with MKOverlays in a "3d" environment.  Technical notes in the answer to this question:
[How do I show MKOverlay above MKAnnotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240855/how-do-i-show-mkoverlay-above-mkannotations)

Comment: I found this, too. 
I'm working from Norway and they don't have 3D Buildings here, but actually they could be added. So you need to disable buildings at all if you want to show overlays inside a building