# MKAnnotationview not stick to MKPolyline Overlay route

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkpolyline

I am adding MKPolyline using an array of lat long values. When I draw annotation over the polyline then Annotation view goes above Trees,flyovers and MKPolyline goes below these objects. Is there any way to solve this problem? 
What I am trying is below:

```
    // access location array to get lat long values

            NSInteger numberOfSteps = locations.count;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
            for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) {
                CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:index];
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
                coordinates[index] = coordinate;
            }

         MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline     polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
            [_routeMapView addOverlay:polyLine level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
```

//Here I am adding custom annotation pin.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomPointAnnotation class]])
        return nil;

    NSString *reuseId = @"test";

    MKAnnotationView *anView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (anView == nil) {
        anView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:point reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        anView.canShowCallout = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        anView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
    //the view is dequeued or created...

    CustomPointAnnotation *cpa = (CustomPointAnnotation *)annotation;
    anView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:cpa.imageName];
    return anView;
}

// show route from source to destination

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 4;
        return renderer;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Here is what I am having issue :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate from this: [How do I show MKOverlay above MKAnnotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240855/how-do-i-show-mkoverlay-above-mkannotations)

As suggested there since iOS 7.0+, when you add your MKOverlay to the map, use the `addOverlay:level:` method. This allows you to specify the z-position of the overlay. One of the highest z-positions for the overlay as defined by `MKOverlayLevels` is `MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels:`

> Place the overlay above map labels, shields, or point-of-interest
>   icons but below annotations and 3D projections of buildings.

Comment: Hi @pesch , thanks for reply but the above link is doing reverse of what I want. Actually annotation pin is showing correctly above the polyline but at some places where polyline passes below Trees,flyovers then I want annotation pin should also pass below these .

Comment: From what I understand, the vertical level for your `MKPolyline` is not OK. Why don't you try changing it's level?

Comment: you mean to change its level to MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels ?. But this is not helping either because polyline still goes under Trees and bridges.